# Rewriting multiple URL in the same depth with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I lately started to use htaccess to rewrite my URL's but i've got some trouble with it. Im not sure if URL depth is the right name in english, but i don't know how to define what URL links to wich page with the same URL depth. For example,

I've got the page:  example.com/page1.php?var1=x&var2=y
and the page:        example.com/page2.php?var3=a&var4=b

I'd like to rewrite them to

```
    example.com/x/y/
    example.com/a/b/
```

The problem is, when i use an URL with a “depth” of 2 slashes, the browser doesn't know which page it has to go. Can someone help me get a solution.

Comment: What kind of values do x,y and a,b have? Do e.g. x,y only contain numbers, and a,b only characters. If that is the case you could easily distinguish between the two with some regular expressions. Otherwise you have to go with Jon Lin's suggestion.

Comment: they are both characters so i'll go Jon Lin's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add something else to the URL to indicate what base-page to send the query string to if there's nothing in the query string that can be used to determine this. For example: `example.com/1/x/y/` -> `example.com/page1.php?var1=x&var2=y` and `example.com/2/a/b/` -> `example.com/page2.php?var3=a&var4=b`.